# Пропадает фон блока на iphone

Tags: css

при просмотре на iphone пропадает цвет фона, становится как будто прозрачным, вот все стили которые заданы блоку
    `position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    display: none;

```
width: 100%;
height: 99%;

text-align: center;;

background-color: rgba(76,103,160);`
```

Comment: background-color: rgba(76,103,160,1); или

Comment: background-color: rgb(76,103,160);

Comment: text-align: center;; => text-align: center;